# Узнать количество тегов div на странице сайта

Tags: javascript

Мне дали такое задание: напишите скрипт для своей страницы,  который будет считать количество тегов div и выведет результат на странице.
Пытался выполнить так, но нечего не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
 function myFunc() {
    const myDiv = document.body.querySelector( "div" );
    for( let i = 0; i < Collection.length; i++){
     console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript файл с кодом необходимо подключать в конце body

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(divs.length);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Или отслеживать, что DOM загрузился, и только тогда выполнять код (тут пример со span, потому что stackoverflow сниппет добавляет свои div'ы)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadDOM);

function loadDOM() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  console.log(spans.length);
}
```

```html
<span>Контент</span>
<span>
  <span>Контент 1</span>
</span>
```

Как добавить к документу ваше число:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadDOM);

function loadDOM() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  const output = document.querySelector('.output');
  
  output.innerHTML = spans.length + ' span\'a';
}
```

```html
<span>Контент</span>
<span>
  <span>Контент-1</span>
</span>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: да, только так заработало

Comment: допустим, я захочу вывести его на страницу, при помощи document.write , то он будет ругаться, как это исправить?

Comment: @HLEBHLEB кого его? количество span или число span'ov?

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadDOM);

function loadDOM() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll(div');
  document.write(spans.length); 
}

Comment: то у меня перекрывает всю страницу

Comment: @HLEBHLEB всё работает, document.write перезаписывает страницу

Comment: может вы меня не правильно поняли? но у меня вместо страницы, белый экран и с выводом счетчика div. Но мне нужно просто страницу и в уголке тот самый счетчик

Comment: да, простите, я идиот. Вся проблема была в том, что я 2 раза подключил js ко странице и теги не считались.

Answer (score 0):

во-первых вы неправильно используете querySelector:

```
document.body.querySelector( "div" );
```

надо

```
document.querySelector( "div" );
```

а во-вторых это же не jquery, для того чтобы получить список всех тегов надо использовать

```
document.querySelectorAll( "div" );
```

**т.е. код должен быть таким:**

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(divs.length);
```

P.S.

а что у вас в коде такое `Collection` вообще не понятно

Comment: он выдает 0 в консоль, но!!! на странице 1 div

Comment: у меня на тестовом примере все нормально -

Comment: и да, можете кинуть откуда можно почитать об этом всем

Comment: очень странно что все нормально, у меня выдает 0 при том что 2 тега див

Comment: прямо в консоли ввел `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div').length);` - показало 2 на страницу где `<div><div></div></div>` - так что посмотрите что у вас там не так - возможно вы получаете список селекторов до того как они у вас будут добавлены на страницу. Что именно почитать?

Comment: вот @Михаил Камахин привел тот же код - у него работает

Comment: странно, я понимаю что должно работать, подключил даже снизу страницы, но он не хочет работать.

Comment: через консоль если писать самому, то все робит

Comment: а само не выводит

Comment: и да, прочитать про все команды js

Comment: вот тут можно почитать: https://learn.javascript.ru/